# Which shells (if any) avoid reading heredocs into memory all at once?

Tags: shell, here-document

Are there any good techniques for structuring huge, auto-generated shell scripts so that they can be executed by `sh` even if the file won't fit in memory? Also, is there any kind of guarantee that a heredoc will not be read into memory all at once by the shell itself? Which shells avoid storing the heredocs in memory in practice, can a conforming `sh` on some arbitrary machine be relied on to do this?

I'm reading about GNU `shar` and was wondering whether it could be used for files that are too large to fit into memory. It uses heredocs to store content.

```
sed -e 's/^X//' << 'SHAR_EOF' | uudecode &&
Msome binary content
Xsome text content
SHAR_EOF
```

However, there are multiple such heredocs, and there some fixed-nonheredoc content at the end of the `shar` script that presumably needs to be parsed before any part of the script can be executed. If the shell didn't parse the whole script, it would be otherwise it would be impossible to reject ill-formed scripts before the first command is executed.

Here's a snippet of the trailing shell comments from a shar archive:

```
...
else
test `LC_ALL=C wc -c < 'a.binary'` -ne 126472 && \
  ${echo} "restoration warning:  size of 'a.binary' is not 126472"
  fi
fi
if rm -fr ${lock_dir}
then ${echo} "x - removed lock directory ${lock_dir}."
else ${echo} "x - failed to remove lock directory ${lock_dir}."
     exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Most shells process scripts line-by-line (try it); have you encountered this as an actual problem?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I haven't encountered this as an actual problem, no. I was under the (apparently mistaken) impression that certain kinds of syntax errors must be rejected by the shell up-front, before executing any commands. Evidently there is no such requirement. (I just tried adding an extra `)` on the last line of a very long script, and the syntax error was only detected by bash when it encountered that line.)

Comment: If your heredoc is tens of gigs large, make it a regular doc and you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the shell will or will not load the whole here document in memory. Huge scripts are not typical, so this isn't a case that shell implementers are particularly likely to optimize. It is even somewhat undesirable that the whole script is not loaded into memory before execution starts to execute it, but all the common shells do execute before fully loading, which means that they execute garbage if the script file is modified during execution.

Experimentally, on Debian jessie, dash, bash, mksh and zsh load a 130kB here document into memory, whereas ksh93 copies 64kB chunks without allocating more memory. So the only way to use a here document that doesn't fit in memory is to ensure that your script is executed with ksh93 (or maybe ksh88) — and before doing so, please ensure that this is the case with other versions, I haven't verified that the behavior is the same with all builds of ksh.

What you can do more portably is to put all the data at the end of the script, and use `tail -c $offset` to extract the payload. It works in practice because none of the usual shells load the script fully into memory before executing it. This method has the advantage that the payload can be binary — here documents can't contain the end-of-heredoc string or null bytes.

If your script is constant, you can hard-code the offset of the payload. If it isn't, you can put a distinguished marker at the end of the script and use awk to determine its location:

```
offset=$(awk '{offset += length($0) + 1}
              $0 == "# payload starts here (do not remove this magic comment)" {
                  print offset; exit
              }')
…
tail -c "$offset" <"$0" — …
…
# payload starts here (do not remove this magic comment)
```

If you have more than one payload, you'll need a more complex command to extract them. Beware that `head -c` does not exist in all unix variants. You can use `dd ibs=1 count=$bytes` to achieve the same effect, but it may be very slow as many `dd` implementations will copy one byte at a time. What I would recommend is to append a tar archive and extract files by name from it.